# PHP: array_push inside a class

Tags: php, arrays

Hi Im new to PHP and trying to implement a class. Inside the class one of my variables is an array. Basically, what I am confused about is how do I initialize the array and then add an element to it using a function. This is the code I have so far but Im getting a syntax error message in the IDE.

```
<?php
 class Food
 {
  var $foodName = "";
  var $foodCals = "";
  var $foodDesc = "";
  var $foodPrice = "";
  var $numSides = "";
  $sidesArray = array();

  function addSide($sideItem)
  {
    array_push($sidesArray, "$sideItem");
  }

 }
?>
```

Get a syntax error that says:

```
Syntax error: unexpected: $sidesArray expected: function, const, var, }, static, abstract, final, private, protected, public
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your member variable like so in the function:

```
$this->sidesArray
```

And in the class declare it like so:

```
public $sidesArray;
```

I recommend you read [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) on php.net.